# Concatenation in HTML using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

My AngularJS controller (called 'search') has the variables:

```
this.redInfo = [...];
this.blueInfo = [...];
this.greenInfo = [...];
this.tableSelector = ''; //this can either be 'red', 'blue', or 'green'
```

I'm trying to do an `ng-repeat` where the info that gets repeated is dependent on the `tableSelector`. Is this possible? This is what I have now:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in {{'search.' + search.tableSelector + 'Info'}} track by $index">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're currently attempting isn't possible. You can make a method that returns the appropriate repeat array:

```
this.getColorArray = function() {
   if (this.search.tableSelector == "red") return this.redInfo
   ...
}
```

Then repeat over that:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in search.getColorArray() track by $index">
```

Depending on the array site and other watchers on the page, this could impact performance. If you know where `tableSelector` changes - you can always set your repeat array at that point and avoid the extra overhead in the $digest cycles.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) property accessor:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in search[search.tableSelector + 'Info'] track by $index">
```